# Retrieve new entity (not proxied) inside a transaction in java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, rollback

### **Retrieve NEW (not proxied) entity inside a transaction in Java with Hibernate**

In java, it's possible to retrieve a new instance of a specific entity without retrieving the ones that hibernate proxies ?

Suppose that we have a method like this

```
@Transaction 
public void parentMethod(String id){
    childMethod(id); //perform operation on entity associated with id
    repository.findById(id);//this needs to retrieve entity from new session
}
```

And the child nested method like this:

```
public void childMethod(String id){
    //retrieves and perform save operation on entity associated with the id
    EntityTest test=repository.findById(id);
    .........update operations..............
    repository.save(test);
}
```

*Consider that i NEED to perform the findById, at the end of the **parentMethod**, to order the collections inside the entity (annotated with @OrderBy)*

If i'm not wrong, when childMethod perform (for example) save operation on the entity, also proxies the result in the session, and if we (in the parentMethod) perform the findById it retrieves that entity and not a new one, so:

1. childMethod retrieve entity with findById (nested collections are ordered)--> proxies result
2. childMethod update entity with save (nested collections are not ordered)--> update the proxy with the result
3. parentMethod perform a findById (nested collections are not ordered)--> retireves the proxy entity

How can i retrieve a new instance outside the session to ensure the collections order? considering that we are inside a transaction and if something goes wrong with the last findById i need the save operations to be rollback?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on your 'proxy' vs 'new' terminology, as JPA/Hibernate are returning 'the' managed instance for your entity data. But it seems you not maintaining the order with your updates - that is a requirement to avoid issues like this, and the overhead involved in having JPA query the database to fix it. Fix though is simply to force the object to be refreshed after flushing the context (or committing the transaction) by calling entityManager.refresh(entity). You might create your own 'findAndRefreshById(id)' method to accomplish it and avoid the overhead when necessary

Comment: i mean that the update returns a value that is "cached" in the session and if you try to retrieve that entity after it will return the cached value (in this case not ordered).